# Is there a signature of a first-order language that characterize the class of regular languages?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, regular-language, finite-model-theory

[A previous question on this site](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9950/what-is-the-minimal-extension-of-fo-that-captures-the-class-of-regular-languages) was about extending the first-order logic with logical constants (quantifiers, fixed-point operators, etc.) to obtain a logical characterization of the class of regular languages.

Alternatively, one could try to get a characterization by expanding the signature of the first-order language, i.e., by allowing new kind of atomic formulas.  For example, in Straubing's *Finite Automata, Formal Logic and Circuit Complexity*, first-order logic with arbitrary number predicates is considered, and it is shown that it characterize the circuit complexity class AC$^0$.  Can a similar thing be done to the class of regular languages?  Or is it known that this is simply impossible?

Comment: You already have the answer: no matter what you put in the signature, first-order definable classes of models are recognizable in AC^0, hence cannot express non-AC^0 regular languages. What else do you want to know?